# Python: Create List Containing 10 Successive Integers Starting with a Number

Tags: python, list, integer

I want to know how to create a list called "my_list" in Python starting with a value in a variable "begin" and containing 10 successive integers starting with "begin".

For example, if `begin = 2`, I want `my_list = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]`

Comment: You shouldn't call any variable a name that shadows a built in keyword

Comment: Have a look at `range()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you cannot user a variable/list name that is the name of builtin keyword< Simply you can use `range()` to do this:

```
begin = 3
my_list = []
end = begin+10
for i in range(begin, end):
    my_list.append(i)

print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sayse mentioned, you should not name the variable `list`.

If you like to have a list like this, you can do it as follows:

```
my_list = list(range(2, 2+10))
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use extend method of list and range function.

`start = 5
my_list = []
my_list.extend(range(start,start+11))
print(my_list)`

Answer (score 0):

```
[*range(begin, begin+10)]
```

*This is for python3*